# ModalViewController loading on top of another Modal

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

There may be a better way to do this, and please direct me if there is.

I'm creating an **UIImagePickerController** with an overlayView in viewDidAppear for 'choose from library', 'take photo', 'flash' 'camera source', etc.

```
// Set up the camera
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] 
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = [self cameraOverlayView];
cameraOverlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;

imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

I then have an IBAction that calls my 'choose from library function', loading another UIImagePickerController to choose a photo from the device.

```
- (IBAction)library:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *libraryPicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];

    libraryPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    libraryPicker.delegate = self;

    [self.imagePicker presentModalViewController:libraryPicker animated:YES];
}
```

I'm getting a white bar across the top about the size of a status bar when the 'choose from library' modal is presented.  I know it has something to do with overlaying a modal on top of a modal, but I don't know how to solve it. (IE, my view layout for 'take photo' navigates fine, although doesn't display the additional 'choose from library' modal).

Any ideas?  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[self presentModalViewController:libraryPicker animated:YES];
```

Instead of

```
[self.imagePicker presentModalViewController:libraryPicker animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem indefinitely.  I knew it was something with my view hierarchy :)