# Adding CameraOverlayView on presentModalViewController gives me white space

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I've spent the last three hours here on StackOverlow and the rest of the day on Google but unfortunately I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm in a view launched by presentModalViewController: in this view I got some buttons and one is calling an IBAction method who will open UIImagePickerController instance modally.

Until here it's all ok: what I'd like to do is make a custom UIToolBar with 3 button (to open Photo Library, Make a photo, Cancel). I did a new UIView with these objects and I thought I could add in this way:

```
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [picker setDelegate:self];
    [picker setAllowsEditing:NO];

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    CGRect overlayFrame = CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44);
    cameraOverlayView.frame = overlayFrame;
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlayView;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

I see my custom toolbar at the bottom, but on top of this there's a white space until the UIImagePickerController of the camera: for what I see, the sum of the blank space and my UIToolBar is equal to the CameraControls (turned off).
When I tap on "photo library" button, I can choose a picture, it works but starting from that point I will see the white space on the parents Views (after the dismissModalViewController:animated).

I can't see a way to fix this.

The most similar topic I found is this: 
[ModalViewController loading on top of another Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073110/modalviewcontroller-loading-on-top-of-another-modal)
but it doesn't help or work for me.

Any help, at this point, would be very appreciated.

Thank you.
Fab